# Can't access value property from html form - uknown behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html form which I cannot access the value property of the fields for some reason I have no idea...

```
<form id="player">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Player 1" id="two_player_one" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="two_player_one">Player 1:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Player 2" id="two_player_two" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="two_player_two">Player 2:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Cards in the first round" id="two_player_one_round_one" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate">
      <label for="two_player_one_round_one">Round 1:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Cards in the first round" id="two_player_two_round_one" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate">
      <label for="two_player_two_round_one">Round 1:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="button" class="btn grey lighten-1" value="Enviar">
            </div>
</form>
```

I tried using this javascript code to read each input-field by its id attribute.

```
let two_player_one = document.getElementById('two_player_one');
let two_player_two = document.getElementById('two_player_two').value;
let two_player_one_round_one = document.getElementById('two_player_one_round_one').value;
let two_player_two_round_one = document.getElementById('two_player_two_round_one').value;
console.log(two_player_one, two_player_two, two_player_one_round_one, two_player_two_round_one);
```

However the only thing that shows in the log is the html tag, but when I try to access the value it doesn't show anything. I have tried changing the type of the submit button from submit to button, but nothing seems to work out.
Here is a screenshot of the form and the console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Sbb.png)

Comment: when are you running the code ? (*also all the `for` attributes on t he `label` elements are pointing to wrong inputs*)

Comment: I am running at the end of the body tag. I corrected the labels, however did not affect anything.

Comment: You need to run the code after you have entered text in the input elements. Otherwise you get their initial value which is empty. You need to run the code in response to some event or user action, for example when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: It worked, thank you.